# C# - PostgreSQL (NpgSql) bytea data transfer progress

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I am using PostgreSQL databases from C# with the NpgSql .Net connector.

I want to have a progress bar when I transfer a bytea to and from a PostgreSQL. I have searched a lot but I cannot find any possible work around.

What I use is a PostgreSQL function that inserts or retrieve a file stored in a bytea column. Perhaps, I can store the file size when I upload it from my application to set the ProgressBar.Maximum property, but I do not know how to see the current amount of bytes transferred in the NpgsqlConnection (or NpgsqlCommand).

Thank you very much in advanced,
Ignacio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dear **Stackoverflow community**,

I have asked this question in the pgFoundary and Francisco kindly answered my questions as follows. I want to share it with you.

---

> Regarding your question, I think this isn't possible because Npgsql
>   doesn't report back how many bytes have been written to the database
>   while sending the data.
>
> One possible workaround would you to use the Large Object support (
>   you can find a working example in manual.npgsql.org ) where your
>   application would send bytes in blocks so you could update your UI
>   about the progress.

---

Thank you,
Ignacio.